# Using Ubuntu subsystem on Windows made entire GIT repository modified

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu subsystem on my Windows 10. Everything was fine until I went to see my local git repository for changes, after `git checkout` my entire project was marked modified. This is my output of `git diff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have to set the line-ending for Git (on Linux) to Windows (or keep them "native", as checked out)... when overwriting Windows line-endings with Linux line-endings, the result looks about like this. just revert and then configure Git before checking out again:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

one can also define all of that (even for specific file-types) with a `.gitattributes` file.

alternatively, commit those line-endings to the local repo and then use a text-editor, which does support them... meanwhile even the infamous `Notepad` has received an update, to be able to do that (most editors come with a small line-feeds/text-encoding indicator, to the bottom-right). also see [dealing with line-endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) (in case `autocrlf` should not work as excepted).

Comment: `git config --global core.autocrlf true` fixed it, thanks